# indexed broken links missing the handle Dspace

Tags: java, dspace

My repository built in dspace has a problem in indexing some addresses.

I have identified that some indexers systems using the repository return missing broken links the "handle" in the URL.

I honestly have no idea what can be. But I think the problem is in dspace or some kind of setup? If someone can give me a light.

One of the indexer system using the repository. And all with the same problem of broken links:

http://feb.ufrgs.br/feb/consulta;jsessionid=12AB6177AB237B668E882966489A68E8?consulta=educa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20a%20dist%C3%A2ncia

as in example broken link: http://www.educapes.capes.gov.br/capes/5822

Comment: Is this issue limited to a specific web crawler?  You provided a sample broken link. What is an example of a correct link to your repository?  I have seen some indexers encounter problems indexing /discover links within my repository, but I cannot tell if this is the same issue.

Comment: the correct link would be:

http://www.educapes.capes.gov.br/handle/capes/15735

Comment: missing the word "handle".